# how to close dialog in PrimeFaces by click outside dialog?

Tags: primefaces

close to dialog in primefaces by click outside of dialog! Provided that when click in dialog do not close, but by click outside dialog close to dialog!

Comment: Could you please edit your question to be more clear what you want to achieve, what have you tried and what issues are you currently have. and follow [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Break down your problem... First is 'detect a click outside the dialog'. -> Pure HTML/JS issue. Secondly 'close a dialog from javascript' -> Pure RTFM issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can set your dialog modal="true", this will generate overall screen block, just behind your dialog.

set your dialog with  widgetVar="someVar"

That is just a div with some properties and it will have an id like j_idt94_modal
so you can get it by selector

```
$( "div[id*='modal']" ).on( "click", PF('someVar').hide());
```

Comment: It's weird normally it should work but I got an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined